# How do you run Sinatra in development mode with a virtual directory?

Tags: sinatra

On production my application runs in a virtual directory 
eg `/virt/action`

```
get '/action'
...
end
```

I want to have the `/virt` also when running sinatra in development mode, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Rack middleware. You should be able to use a middleware class only in development that intercepts /virt/action and remaps it to /action.  This may be overkill in your case, but [Rack Rewrite](http://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) would probably do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I used varnish in front of my webserver (nginx) which modifies the url sent and voila... same urls in dev and prd.